# Storing Firestore Timestamp in User Defaults

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, nsuserdefaults

I am a new Swift developer.  I am using Xcode 10.2 and Swift 4.2.

I am trying to store a Firestore `Timestamp` in the user defaults and retrieve it.  The problem I'm having is the first time I retrieve the timestamp, it may be nil so I would like to have a default value.  But I don't know how to format any date as a Firestore `Timestamp` so I can indicate a default of January 1, 2000.  I reviewed the firebase documentation but could not find how to take a readable date and format it as a timestamp (it seems all the the methods are deprecated by firebase).

Here is my code to read the stored date with an attempt to use January 1, 2000 as a default, but this does not work:

```
// Get a reference to a default date of January 1, 2000.
    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    let defaultDate = dateformatter.date(from: "01/01/2000 12:00 AM")

// Get the last date the table was updated.
    let lastDateNSData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constants.LocalStorage.rateTableTimeStamp) as? Data
    let lastDate = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: lastDateNSData ?? Data(Timestamp(date: defaultDate!))) as! Timestamp
```

I am getting an error on the `Data(Timestamp(date: defaultDate!))` that says `'Timestamp' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'` I think it is because of how I formatted `defaultDate` using `dateformatter`. But I don't know another way to do it.

In case it helps, here is my code to write the current date as a timestamp to defaults:

```
// Update the timestamp.
    let now = Timestamp(date: Date())
    let nsNow = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: now)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(nsNow, forKey: Constants.LocalStorage.rateTableTimeStamp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it as `object`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey:"key")
```

And read

```
if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "key") as? Date {
   //// 
}
```

---

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Opened") { 
    // set date here
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Opened")
}
```

Comment: So in your answer above, I can set the current date in the defaults without converting it to NSData, right?  But what if I read the defaults and it is nil?  How do I indicate a default Firestore Timestamp as January 1, 2000?  Or just a default date of January 1, 2000 that I can convert to a Firestore Timestamp?

Comment: Would this work?  let defaultDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 946684800)

Comment: you can have a Boolean value indicating first open and inside it's if statement read or set the needed default date, yes your `let defaultDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 946684800) ` is correct but `946684800` is 2000 not 2001 use https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Got it.  Here's the code that now works:         if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constants.LocalStorage.rateTableTimeStamp) as? Date {
            lastDate = Timestamp(date: date)
        } else {
            lastDate = Timestamp(date: defaultDate)
        }
`